# explode получение значения тк из строки

Tags: php

В фалике list.txt храню данные вот так:

```
я ты

мы вы
```

и выбираю ответ по GET параметру

```
 $list = file_get_contents('list.txt');
 $exp = explode($_GET['r'], $list);
 print_r($exp);
```

Например если `$_GET['r']` будет иметь значение "я" то в `$exp[1]` должно быть "ты" но в место него там "ты мы вы"

Comment: Все вам правильно возвращает, так как в `$list` у вас весь текст, а не одна срока находится.

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте так:

```
<?php
    // загружаем файл в массив построчно
    $file = file('list.txt');

    // пробегаем по массиву
    foreach ($file as $file_row) {
        // разбиваем строку по символу табуляции на пару значений
        $file_val = explode("\t", $file_row);
        // если первое значение совпадает с переданным методом GET
        if ($file_val[0] == $_GET['r']) {
            // выводим второе значение без правых пробельных символов
            echo rtrim($file_val[1]);
            // останавливаем пробег по массиву
            break;
        }
    }
?>
```

При этом в текстовом документе в качестве разделителя между парой сделайте символ табуляции.

Comment: Нечего не выводит

Comment: Не выводить может, если в файле не находит значение из GET (в частности по регистру). Или же если вы не сделали в качестве разделителя в текстовом документе символ табуляции. Других причин не вижу.

Answer (score 0):

Все решил проблему, Дмитрий помог :)

```
$file = file('list.txt');
foreach ($file as $file_row) {
    $file_val = explode($_GET['r'], $file_row);
    echo $file_val[1];
}
```

Comment: Я бы добавил условие для останова пробега и функцию rtrim для удаления символа перевода строки из выводимого значения,

Comment: А вообще это неправильный код. Дотачивайте мой под свою задачу. У вас произойдет вывод при первом вхождении переменной из GET в строку. Если с помощью GET передаёте слово "я", а в файле будет строка "земля дегенератами полна", то на странице будет красоваться фраза " дегенератами полна".