# Explode как вывести тк строку

Tags: php

В фалике list.txt храню данные вот так:

> я ты
>
> мы вы

и выбираю ответ по GET параметру

```
 $list = file_get_contents('list.txt');
 $exp = explode($_GET['r'], $list);
 print_r($exp);
```

Например если `$_GET['r']` будет иметь значение "я" то в `$exp[1]` должно быть "ты" но в место него там "ты мы вы"

Comment: Ответил в дубле вопроса выше.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [explode получение значения тк из строки](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/448435/explode-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8)

Comment: `file_get_contents` получает значение **всех** строк из файла, а не одной, в которой содержится `я мы`